References for Rigorous Analysis of ML Techniques for PDEs
I’m looking for a book or resource that rigorously analyzes machine learning techniques (e.g., neural networks, operator learning) for solving PDEs like the Laplace, heat, and wave equations. Ideally, it should cover error bounds and applications to these classical PDEs. Any recommendations?

My understanding is that one of the key issues with these methods is their lack of rigourous error bounds. It is current enough research that I doubt you will be able to find a book or generally approachable source. I think a trawl through Google Scholar is your best bet

+1 to that, the whole theoretical foundation of ML is lacking behind, sadly. I have attended a few talks recently that specifically mentioned this. I would also like to add that a common approach is to learn the "Greens function" for the differential operator and IIRC, there are some papers out there with proper error estimates.

Unfortunately, as a player in this game, I would say there is no satisfying theory on the error estimate, as simple and elegant as the Lax equivalence principle, in the traditional sense. Universal Approximation Theorem (UAT) tackles existence and how to get there is empirically not possible (the Lottery ticket hypothesis), as there is a disjointness between the PDE theory (normally given in the context of Sobolev/Besov spaces) and the optimization used.
However, if you are willing to get into the realm of probabilistic error bounds by treating these function-valued neural network (simple MLP), or operator-valued neural networks (Fourier, Transformer, reduced basis) as representation of distributions, I recommend two papers that I ask my students to read:

Nelsen, N. H., & Stuart, A. M. (2021). The random feature model for input-output maps between banach spaces. SIAM Journal on Scientific Computing, 43(5), A3212-A3243.
de Hoop, M. V., Kovachki, N. B., Nelsen, N. H., & Stuart, A. M. (2023). Convergence rates for learning linear operators from noisy data. SIAM/ASA Journal on Uncertainty Quantification, 11(2), 480-513.

